# Set a default Color for all ComboBox in an easy way

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, combobox

I looked on several topics, but I could not find an easy way to define the default color of my combobox.

What I am trying for now is the following :

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox">
   <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource WindowBorderColor}"/>
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundColor}"/>
   <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
      </Trigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
   <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource WindowBorderColor}"/>
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundColor}"/>
   <Setter Property="Template">
       <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
               <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                   <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
               </Border>
              <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                 <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundColor}"/>
                 </Trigger>
                 <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource WindowBorderColor}"/>
                 </Trigger>
              </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
           </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
  </Style>
```

But until now it is not working yet(Background remains grey), all what I can do is set the color of ComboBox Items :

[image]

**EDIT :**

I could manage to do "something", the colors are applied correctly, but now the text in the TexBox is not appearing(appearing correctly in popup) :

```
<Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="Yellow"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    Background="Green" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Border x:Name="splitBorder" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                        Margin="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                        Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}">
                        <Path x:Name="arrow"
                            Data="F1 M 0,0 L 2.667,2.66665 L 5.3334,0 L 5.3334,-1.78168 L 2.6667,0.88501 L0,-1.78168 L0,0 Z"
                            Fill="DarkCyan" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Border x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" Background="White" />
</ControlTemplate>
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border x:Name="Border" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" CornerRadius="2"
            Background="Blue"
            BorderThickness="1" />
        <Border 
            Grid.Column="0"
            CornerRadius="2,0,0,2" 
            Margin="1" 
            Background="green" 
            BorderThickness="0,0,1,0">

        </Border>

        <Path 
            x:Name="Arrow"
            Grid.Column="1"     
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
<Style TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource WindowBorderColor}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundColor}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Grid>
                    <ToggleButton 
                            Name="ToggleButton" 
                            Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" 
                            Grid.Column="2" 
                            Focusable="false"
                            IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                            ClickMode="Press">
                    </ToggleButton>
                    <ContentPresenter
                        Name="ContentSite"
                        IsHitTestVisible="False" 
                        Margin="3,3,23,3"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" Style="{x:Null}" Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="1,1,1,1"
                            Focusable="True" 
                            Background="Transparent"
                            Visibility="Hidden"
                            IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"/>
                    <Popup 
                        Name="Popup"
                        Placement="Bottom"
                        IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                        AllowsTransparency="True" 
                        Focusable="False"
                        PopupAnimation="Slide">
                        <Grid 
                                Name="DropDown"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="True"                
                                MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                                MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                            <Border 
                                x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                                Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="1">

                            </Border>
                            <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Grid>
                    </Popup>


                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Since the`ComboBox` is composed of several parts, you have to override the templates of those parts. You can modify the default styles to meet your requirements: [Microsoft Docs: ComboBox Styles and Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/combobox-styles-and-templates)

Comment: @BionicCode yes saw it after reading all code from TheLastShark, but still didn't manage to do it, or the color is not applied, or I the content of TextBox is not visible. Will go further on it.

Comment: @BionicCode could you have a look to my Edit please? seems I made something wrong, all is ok, but the text inside TextBox is not appearing

Comment: In the `ComboBox` style find the `ContentPresenter` named  _ContentSite_. Add the following attribute to it: `Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"`. You mustr have accidently removed it.

Comment: @BionicCode almost done with it thanks... still a problem, my Comboboxes are list of objects, so I always use `"DisplayMemberPath"` in xaml (`DisplayMemberPath="MyString"`) , the problem is if I do `Content="{TemplateBinding DisplayMemberPath}"` I display the name of the field (`"MyString"`), but not its value

Comment: `DisplayMemberPath` internally  overrides the `ItemTemplate`. To make it work add the following attribute to the `ContententPresenter` named _ContentSite_:  `ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"`

Comment: @BionicCode thanks, just perfect, couldn't find anything about it by myself ^^'.

Comment: You are welcome. To be safe from future  modifications, just replace the `ContentPresenter`_ContentSite_ with this one: `<ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsHitTestVisible="false" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a copy of the current `ComboBox` styles and edit it.
Right click on the control(`ComboBox`) on the design window and go to `Edit Template` then select `Edit a Copy`
This will create the default template, you can edit it as you wanted.

You can edit the following part to set the default background color

```
<Border x:Name="templateRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundColor}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Border}">
   <Border x:Name="splitBorder" Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Transparent">
      <Path x:Name="arrow" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Fill="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Glyph}" Data="F1 M 0,0 L 2.667,2.66665 L 5.3334,0 L 5.3334,-1.78168 L 2.6667,0.88501 L0,-1.78168 L0,0 Z"/>
   </Border>
</Border>
```

Comment: I tried the `Edit Template`, but this adds some code in my xaml file, 177 lines of code, and my xaml is not working anymore. Isn't it a way to do it in App.xaml more simply?

Comment: yeah you can copy it to the `App.xaml`
or you can put it in the `<Window.Resources> </Window.Resources>` of the same xaml page your UI is in.

Comment: need to copy the whole code? O_o, I believed there would be a way to do it with 5-10 lines of code instead of all that pack...

Comment: this is the full style of the default `ComboBox`, so yeah you need to copy the whole thing, unfortunately.
Maybe there's a better way.